# How to load an external .class file into my Java application at runtime?

Tags: java, web-services, model-view-controller, jboss

I want to create an application that is as `web-service` to deliver results straight from data base `procedures` or `java classes`, depending on user request via `REST URL`.

I want it to be extendable in a way that I **won't** need to rebuild the `WAR file` every time a developer creates a new `Controller Class` . Instead, I should only need to put a `.class file` in a specific folder and then register the new .class file in a `XML Config File` of this application.

**Is it possible? How can I** call this external class from inside the application, create an object based on it and then execute one of it's methods according to user definition in the URL?

*With PHP it is much easier because you don't compile it.*

Comment: Just a note: I used to code in php, basic, pascal, clipper etc. But I am newly in Java, just did two projects for Android, but now I am moving to web. Please be nice, I don't know (yet) all the resources Java developers have at their disposal.

Comment: Don't do that. Stick with the usual things java developers do and recompile everything.

Comment: But I want this application to be a generic web-service for my Angular applications, not an API for a specific application. Does that matter?

Comment: No, you can use live-reload / hotswap (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553353/change-a-method-at-runtime-via-a-hot-swap-mechanism and http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html#howto-reload-java-classes-without-restarting) during development but I would not do that in a production environment.

Comment: It is pretty much like this user is asking for in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class