# Automatically reload classes while debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am currently working on big spring boot project which takes around 1 minute to start. While debugging, if i make some changes in some class, I have to restart the whole application again.

Is there any way i could reload only those classes (and beans)  which have been updated while debugging Intellij so that i could quickly see those changes in running application?

Comment: Take a look at Jrebel -> https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4553353/85421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,

As Intellij Idea says :

> Reloading changed classes To reload changed classes
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> On the main menu, choose Run | Reload Changed Classes.
>
> On the main menu, choose Build | Compile "class_name" to recompile an altered class during debug.
>
> In the Reload Changed Classes dialog box, confirm reloading. Results are displayed in the Messages tool window.
>
> Configuring reloading behavior To configure reloading behavior
>
> On the main menu, choose File | Settings, and under Build, Execution, Deployment expand the Debugger node.
>
> Open HotSwap page.
>
> Click one of the radio buttons in the group Reload classes after compilation. You can opt to always reload classes, reload after
> confirmation, or never do it.

Reference
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.3/reloading-classes.html