# Netbeans live/realtime update

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to make NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 live compile like here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dwn_UrItwfw#t=239s

I have tried running it in debug mode the type ctrl + s as commented.
BUt that doesn't work, he(NetBeans) will not live update the code.

How can i make netbeans update the code live(while application running)?

Comment: IDE agnostic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553353/change-a-method-at-runtime-via-a-hot-swap-mechanism Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981746/eclipse-editing-and-running-code-live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run in debug mode
2. Make the change
3. Save the file
4. Press "Apply code changes" from the debug menu or the toolbar.

Note: In the preferences you can set this option to automatically apply code changes.

Make sure your code will pass through that line (e.g. changing an initialization code means you need to reinitialize the object).